# How to add 1 hour with the date currently saved in the db in doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Hi can anybody please help with this, I am trying to add 1 hours with the time save in the DB but can't find any way as doctrine date_add only supports month and day

Thanks
Fahim

```
public function deleteSession($sessionId = null, $sessionName = null)
{
    $flag = false;
    $dql = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->update('EcomBundle:Sessions', 's')
        ->set('s.status', ':status')
        ->setParameter('status', 'deleted')
        ->where('1 = 1');

    if ($sessionId !== null) {
        $dql = $dql->andWhere('s.phpSessId = :phpSessId')
            ->setParameter('phpSessId', $sessionId);
        $flag = true;
    }

    if ($sessionName !== null) {
        $dql = $dql->andWhere(' s.sessionName = :sessionName')
            ->setParameter('sessionName', $sessionName);
        $flag = true;
    }

    if ($flag === false) {
        $dql = $dql->andWhere("DATE_ADD(s.updatedAt, 1, 'HOUR') < :curTime")
        ->setParameter('curTime', new \DateTime('now'));
    }

    $dql = $dql->getQuery();
    $result = $dql->execute();
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could register a custom DQL function for your mysql needs. See "Date Add" paragraph in http://www.doctrine-project.org/2010/03/29/doctrine2-custom-dql-udfs.html. Once you created your class, you'll have to register it in your config.yml file, under `doctrine.orm.entity_managers.default.dql.datetime_functions`. Like this :

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                dql:
                    datetime_functions:
                        date_add:        AppBundle\DQL\MysqlDateAdd #path to your custom date_ad mysql function
```

Comment: Look promising I will try and update here once it is done Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this trick without the need to register a custom DQL function:

```
$oneHour = 1/24;
$dql = $dql->andWhere("DATE_ADD(s.updatedAt, :oneHour, 'DAY') < :curTime")
    ->setParameters(['curTime' => new \DateTime('now'), 'oneHour' => $oneHour]);
```

Comment: Hi dlondero, thanks for your answer but it throws error : QueryException in QueryException.php line 52: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 91: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_COMMA, got '/'

Comment: Fahim updated answer. Previously was just to suggest you can split a day in 24 parts (as the hours) and just use one.

Comment: Hi dlondero, Thank for your help but am am afraid it does not work. The value of the updatedAt is 2016-07-28 18:20:00 and I run the DQL at  2016-07-28 18:55:00, therefore it should not update the status but unfortunately it does.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change

```
if ($flag === false) {
        $dql = $dql->andWhere("DATE_ADD(s.updatedAt, 1, 'HOUR') < :curTime")
        ->setParameter('curTime', new \DateTime('now'));
    }
```

into

```
if ($flag === false) {
        $dql = $dql->andWhere("s.updatedAt < :targetTime")
        ->setParameter('targetTime', (new \DateTime('now'))->modify("-1 hour"));
        }
```

Comment: Thank you ilyass. It was such a simple solution. My mind was only rounding arround date_add which remained useless in this case. Thanks